# Ruby prepend doesn't work for class method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use prepend method in ruby to overwrite methods of a class, here is how my code works:

```
module PrependedModule
  def self.klass_method
    puts 'PrependedModule klass_method'
  end

  def instance_method_a
    puts 'PrepenedModule instance method'
  end
end

class SomeClass
  prepend PrependedModule

  def self.klass_method
    puts 'SomeClass klass_method'
  end

  def instance_method_a
    puts 'SomeClass instance_method'
  end
end

SomeClass.klass_method
SomeClass.new.instance_method_a

#output:
#SomeClass klass_method
#PrependedModule instance method

#expected:
#PrependedModule klass_method
#PrependedModule instance method
```

The output of this script is shown above, as we can see, the instance method `instance_method_a` was overwritten by module `PrependedModule`, but  not the class method `klass_method`, when I called `klass_method` on `SomeClass`, it still executes it's origin method, instead of the one defined in `PrependedModule`.

I'm confused about this and don't know what happend with class methods when using prepend. It would be a great help if anyone can solve this question for me.

Comment: There's no reason for this to work as you expect. Neither `include` nor `prepend` works on 'class methods'.

Comment: @MarekLipka got it, thank u so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Singleton classes do not work that way. You need to explicitly `prepend` the methods to the eigenclass of `SomeClass`:

```
module PrependedModule
  module ClassMethods
    def klass_method
      puts 'PrependedModule klass_method'
    end
  end

  def instance_method_a
    puts 'PrepenedModule instance method'
  end
end

class SomeClass
  # prepending to the class
  prepend PrependedModule
  class << self
    # prepending to the eigenclass
    prepend PrependedModule::ClassMethods
  end

  def self.klass_method
    puts 'SomeClass klass_method'
  end

  def instance_method_a
    puts 'SomeClass instance_method'
  end
end
```

Comment: For those challenged by `class << self`, it might be clearer to write `singleton_class.prepend PrependedModule::ClassMethods`.

Comment: Back in the old days we didn't have `singleton_class`! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I doubt there was `prepend` back in that Stone Age.

Answer (score 6):

With `include` or `prepend` you can only gain access to a module's instance methods<sup>1</sup>. You therefore might ask if there is any reason to define module methods on a module. The answer is a resounding "yes". There are two reasons you might want to do that.

The first has nothing to do with including or prepending the module. You need only look at the module [Math](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Math.html) to understand why you might want to do that. All methods defined on `Math` are module methods. These constitute a library of useful functions. They are of course methods, but since all have `Math` as their receiver, they behave like functions in non-OOP languages.

The second reason is that you might want to define a [callback method](https://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-important-hook-methods/) (aka *hook* method) on a module that is to be included or prepended by another module. The main ones are [Module#included](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-included), [Module#prepended](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-prepended), [Module#extended](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-extended), [Class#inherited](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) and [BasicObject#method_missing](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing). The last of these is an instance method; the others are module methods. An example of `Module#prepended` is given below.

@mudasoba has shown how to confine instance methods to a sub-module `Sub` of `Mod` so that `Mod::Sub` can be prepended (or included) to a class's (or module's) singleton class. A commonly-used *pattern* for doing that employs the callback `Module#prepended`. It follows.

```
module PrependedModule
  module ClassMethods
    def klass_method
      puts 'PrependedModule klass_method'
    end
  end

  def instance_method_a
    puts 'PrepenedModule instance method'
  end

  def self.prepended(mod)
    mod.singleton_class.prepend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

class SomeClass
  def self.klass_method
    puts 'SomeClass klass_method'
  end

  def instance_method_a
    puts 'SomeClass instance_method'
  end

  prepend PrependedModule
end

SomeClass.klass_method
  # PrependedModule klass_method
SomeClass.new.instance_method_a
  # PrepenedModule instance method
```

<sup>1 I've always found it curious that *instance methods* can be defined on modules (that are not classes), considering that such modules cannot have instances. True, these methods become instance methods in classes that include or prepend the module, but keep in mind that those modules can be included or prepended by other modules (that are not classes) as well. One might therefore expect such methods to have some name other than "instance method". Finding a suitable alternative would be a challenge, however, which is perhaps one reason why that nomenclature has persisted.</sup>

Comment: You don't need to call them instance methods. In fact, *there is only one kind of method in Ruby*, so there is no need to qualify them. But modules can have instances, for example every array is an instance of `Enumerable` (as well as of `Array`, `Object`, `Kernel`, and `BasicObject`).

Comment: @Jörg, I may not need to call them *instance methods*, but everyone else will continue to do so, because it's part of the language (e.g., [Module#instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods)). `[].instance_of?(Enumerable) #=> false`, so I don't know how you have defined *instance* in your second sentence. I know you've said many times there is only one kind of method in Ruby. I would like to discuss that with you sometime but I don't think this is the place.

Comment: `instance_of?` only checks for direct instances. `kind_of?` or `is_a?` also checks transitively.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I learned a lot from your answer! Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can comment on when this was introduced, but my personal experience and also suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland in comments section of the selected answer, you can always do

```
class Source
  def self.hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end

module Extension
  def hello
    # you're also allowed to call super from here
    puts "world"
  end
end

Source.singleton_class.prepend Extension
```

Now if you call `Source.hello`, the method from the `Extension` module will be called.

This is also valid for overriding Module's static/class methods But I've mentioned the code explicitly because I've rarely come accross this solution on S/O.

```
module Source
  def self.hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end

module Extension
  def hello
    # you're also allowed to call super from here
    puts "world"
  end
end

Source.singleton_class.prepend Extension
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Foo
  singleton_class.prepend ClassMethods

  def self.hello
    puts "hi"
  end 
end
```

```
module ClassMethods
  def hello
    puts "ho"
  end
end
```